# update plugin via code

Tags: php, wordpress

is it somehow possible to update a wordpress-plugin via another plugin with php code?

i tried something like this

```
$request = wp_remote_post(
'http://wordpress2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
array(
    'body' => array( 
        'plugin' => 'hello-dolly/hello.php',
        'slug' => 'hello-dolly',
        'action' => 'update-plugin',
        '_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'nonce-test' ),
    )
));
```

but this only leads in a 400 status...

I thought this kind of stuff would be easy in wordpress, dumb me! :-D

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

1. after all plugins are loaded add a filter which define to auto-update plugins

   add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( **CLASS**, 'abpr_plugins_loaded' ), 1 );
   public static function abpr_plugins_loaded(){
       add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true');
    }
2. the define some function which will be triggered from something, in my case it is an custom api-url which calls this:

   ```
   public static function update_all_defined_plugins($data){       
       set_site_transient( 'update_plugins', '' );
       wp_maybe_auto_update(); }
   ```

keep in mind that this is some bare stuff here without any code- & results-checking